# Display a function using AJAX

Tags: functions, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display a function using AJAX using a custom plugin. But doesn't seem to work.

My Javascript

```
(function($) {
$(document).on( 'click', 'a.mylink', function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
    url: testing.ajax_url,
        data : {
        action : 'diplay_user_table'
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        jQuery('#user_reponse').html( response );
    }


})
})
})(jQuery);
```

My PHP

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', plugins_url( '/test.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'test', 'testing', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'diplay_user_table');

function diplay_user_table() {
    echo "function is loading in div";
}
```

When I click on link it just displays '0'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not hooking the function to wp_ajax correctly. You need to replace the `my_action` part with your action name that you're using the in AJAX request. In your case it's `display_user_table`. You also need to hook it on to `wp_ajax_nopriv` so that it works for logged out users. Here's your hook with those changes:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_diplay_user_table', 'diplay_user_table');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_diplay_user_table', 'diplay_user_table');
function diplay_user_table() {
    echo "function is loading in div";
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Jacob. It works now. One small thing it still response with the '0'. It displays: function is loading in div0. Any ideas why the '0' is there?

Comment: Make sure to include `wp_die()` in your callback once everything has finished. I left that out. I've updated my answer with it.

Comment: Hope on not push it, but how would I pass a value form the link to the function. For example I wanted to pass the title to the link to a vlue in function?

Comment: You would need to put the value in the `data` object in the ajax request, 'next to' the `'action'`, then it will be available in the `$_POST` variable in your hook.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes I worked it out. But I user $_REQUEST. Seems to be working OK. But I just realized that I can't load any styles or scripts into my div.user_response. Could this be reason? Do you know how I could load styles and scripts into my ajax div. Going a bit mad here trying. First time using AJAX never knew it wouldn't load styles/scripts.

Comment: Why do you need styles or scripts? Just return the HTML and when you add it to the page it will be styled by the stylesheets loaded on that page.

Comment: Thats what I thought it would do but it didn't. I am loading a table and not even the bootstrap css I'm using is loading. Either is any of the js that the table require. Outside the div the table is styled and javascript works, but not inside. I've been reading it has to do with DOM but I can't work it out. Been playing with data types but not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a faster and quicker method, to get rid of the annoying 0 that is chasing every AJAX request to the end. By using a REST API endpoint, you don't need to write different actions for logged-in and non-logged-in users.

Here is a quick example:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'aido14', '/my_path/', array(
            'methods' => 'GET', 
            'callback' => 'diplay_user_table' 
    ) );
});
// Callback function
function diplay_user_table() {
    $data['test1'] = "function is loading in div";
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', plugins_url( '/test.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'test', 'testing', array(
        'ajax_url' => site_url()
    ));
}
```

And your JavaScript:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on( 'click', 'a.mylink', function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: testing.ajax_url + '/wp-json/aido14/my_path',
            data : { parameter-here : value-here 
        },
        success : function( response.test1 ) {
            jQuery('#user_reponse').html( response );
        }
    });
})
})(jQuery);
```

Now, you get the same result by visiting `/wp-json/aido14/my_path`. A neat JSON response which you can use even in mobile apps.

And, as you can see, you can pass several responses in a single request by storing them in an array. This will come in handy for example in contact and login forms.

Comment: Thank you Jack, I just tested and it works too. I'm actually only requiring for logged in users but I can see the advantage.

Comment: You're welcome :) Just in case you need Ajax search or login in the future ;)

Comment: I actually have to do this soon,so cheers. One thing how would pull a parameter from the link in function? example:<a class="mylink" title="the title of page">link</a>. How to get the title(variable) in function?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_diplay_user_table', 'diplay_user_table');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_diplay_user_table', 'diplay_user_table');
function diplay_user_table() {
    ob_start();
    echo "function is loading in div";
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    echo $data;
    die();

}
```